# R to SAP Hana, problems with variable names

Tags: r, hana, r-server

I've got a working connection to a SAP Hana database from my companies R-server. My connection is straight forward and looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)

myQuery <- 'SELECT Var1, Var___2 
FROM .... '

myDB <- odbcConnect("sapName", uid = "user", pwd = "password", DBMSencoding = "UTF-8") 

sqlQuery(myDB, myQuery)
```

My problem is that most queries will work fine. However, some of the variables have been name with 3 underscores, these I cannot get out.

2 out of 3 coworkers can perform the query from R - and it will work. The last has the same error has me. The query will work fine on SAP Hana.

I've checked that all packages are the same version.

I'm at loss at what to look at.

Comment: What is the returned error message?

Comment: Empty column, no error message

Comment: Are your columns using mixed cases in the database? if it does then you need to enclose them in double quotes.

Comment: Anyway, it is really strange that it works for your colleagues and not 2 of you. That makes me thinks it's a package version issue

Comment: Packages are the same, we're running it on the same R-server - the query is the exact same across users. Works for 2 out of 4.

Comment: if you are using the same stack, the same query, then the difference is somewhere else. Are you suing the same credentials to connect to HANA?

Comment: by the way have you considered using the HANA R ML package instead of raw ODBC connection? https://help.sap.com/doc/c48739beb06a4304a98e44b4d5b60a50/2.0.04/en-US/hana.ml.r/html/00Index.html

Comment: I just want to get data out of the Sap Hana database, not do any ML with it.

Comment: You can use it for the built in data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a an issue with how our licenses where created on the SAP HANA database. We where not asked to create a new password when logging on the first time, and this apparantly gives issues in viewing certain types of data.

Solution was to delete and re-create our users, resetting them was not enough.